# Python override 3rd party package single file

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the best way to override python any 3rd party package single file?

Suppose.

I have a package called **foo**. Foo contains file tar.py which have an import line.

tar.py

```
from xyz import abc
# some code
```

how do I replace that single line import

```
# from 
from xyz import abc
# to 
from xyz.xy import abc
```

i want to change this line outside virtualenv in python project

Comment: This import  `from xyz import abc`  is present in so many files so you want to modify in some generic way I didnt understand your doubt clearly Can you elaborate more ?

Comment: As it stands, I have no idea what you're asking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override `builtins.__import__` with a wrapper function that changes the package name to `'xyz.xy'` if it is equal to `'xyz'`:

```
def my_import(name, *args, **kwargs):
    if name == 'xyz':
        name = 'xyz.xy'
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)

import builtins
original_import = __import__
builtins.__import__ = my_import

from foo import tar
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/ComplicatedGrandUnits

Comment: `__builtins__` is an implementation detail that doesn't work the way you think it does. It will usually be a dict rather than a module - try inspecting its value in any module other than `__main__`, and you'll usually find a dict. You need to import `builtins`.

Comment: Indeed. Updated as suggested then.